# Is tmux supports cterm=undercurl used in VIM?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, tmux

In my vim config I've added `undercurl` value for badly spelled words

```
hi SpellBad guifg=NONE cterm=undercurl
```

Outside the tmux it works fine, but inside of it I continue to see like it is set to `underline` instead of `undercurl`.

To clarify that even in vim I couldn't see curly line until I added to my `.vimrc` this:

```
let &t_Cs = "\e[4:3m"
let &t_Ce = "\e[4:0m"
```

I did some long research, it's normal for tmux to behave like this? It seems to me that it doesn't support it at all.

**Software conf**:
*Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS*,
*Tmux 3.0a*,
*Vim 8.0.1453*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your tmux is new enough to support this then you need to add the Smul capability, see https://man.openbsd.org/tmux#TERMINFO_EXTENSIONS:

```
set -as terminal-overrides ',*:Smulx=\E[4::%p1%dm'
```

If you want coloured underlines you wil also need to add Smulc.

Comment: Oh, it seems to work. I have already used `terminal overrides` in my tmux conf, maybe the Smulx value was wrong... Thank you nevertheless.